# combine two search results ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to have two search fields, that however end up combining the two results.
In one filed you can search for the location of a listing and in the other for a keyword, which will look for title and description of the listing. 
When a location and keyword is entered, listings that match both the location and keyword should show. So if I enter San Francisco and Retail, only listings located in SF and with the description or title Retail should pop up.

Feng Chen suggested to do this in one query by the following:

```
self.where("location like ? and (title like ? or description like ?)", query, query)
```

However this does not show a result that matches both the location and the keyword(title, description).
Do I need to change something in my view or anywhere else?

Here is what I have listing.rb

```
def self.locsearch(search)
  query = "%#{search}%"
  if search
    self.where("location like ? and (title like ? or description like ?)", query, query)
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

end

Static_pages_controller.rb

```
def home
@listings = @listings.locsearch(params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
```

home.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag findjobs_path, :controller => 'listings', :action => 'locsearch', :method => 'get' do %>
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, "location"  %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, "keyword"  %>
  <%= submit_tag "search" %>
</p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where is your descsearch method?

Answer (score 1):

You need a descsearch method in your listing model and you need to do

```
# Right now you have @listings = @listings.locsearch(...)
# You need @listings = Listing.locsearch(...)
@listings = Listing.locsearch(params[:search][:location], params[:search][:keyword])
```

And in your listing model

```
def self.locsearch(location, keyword)
  location = "%#{location}%"
  keyword = "%#{keyword}%"
  if !location.bllank? && !keyword.blank?
    self.where("location like ? and (title like ? or description like ?)", location, keyword)
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Yes, sorry I had a descsearch method originally but I got told I only need one search method. I edited my code above

Comment: See the comment in my answer.

Comment: Hey Nick, when I change it it filters for the title and description but not the location. So I put in San Francisco Retail. I get listings with retail in title or description located in SF but also in Chicago.

Comment: Rika, see the changes in my answer. Basically, you should probably separate keyword and location for your search function. hope that helps.

Comment: I'm getting this error
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
highlighting
  @listings = Listing.locsearch(params[:search][:location], params[:search][:keyword])

Comment: The error is too long I created a gist.
Also, thanks for still helping me. 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c4ff2487682d36704f3c
It highlights this line 
 @listings = Listing.locsearch(params[:search][:location], params[:search][:keyword])

Comment: Did you change the if statement looking for the search variable? See edit.

Comment: Yes, I changed it like you suggested and I still get the same error showcased in the gist.
Do you think it could be a formatting/syntax error?
Also, if I visit the index page without doing a search I get this error
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3cb01b890031b95a6c1f

Comment: Also just to clarify,
the search form for keyword and location is on the homepage. After hitting search the results show on the index page.
On the index page, there are usually all listings displayed and the index page has its own simpler search form to search for location, description and title. 
Maybe this helps

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help you without seeing the full code base. I need a lot more to work with.

Comment: Hey, I understand.
Would it be helpful if I create a gist with the other code?
If its too time consuming for you I can understand

Comment: I need to see the whole application at once, otherwise it will be too time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a postgres database, you could try to use the full text search feature to do the above. There is gem pg_search [enter link description here](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search)which will allow you to do so easily. The overhead incurred would be trivial and would provide you greater flexibility in this search problem and any such other ones you might have to solve later.